# video player inside a frame/panel in python raspberry pi desktop application

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

Can anyone give me an idea for displaying a video player inside a frame or panel using python

[Sample image of the requirement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sn07j.png)

Comment: you mean on WEB page?

Comment: nope.I want to build a desktop application